# Django Rest Framework modelserializer not respecting required=False in ImageField

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a django model with some not required fields:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='publications/images', blank=True, null=True)
video = models.FileField(upload_to='publications/videos', blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a ModelSerializer:

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False, allow_empty_file=True)
    video = serializers.FileField(required=False, allow_empty_file=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have an APIView:

```
class PublicationView(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    ...

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PublicationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Everything looks pretty straightforward. But when I send the form from the frontend I get the error:

```
image   [ "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form." ]
```

When I add an image, it works correctly. However, the image field is supposed to be optional. I've read the docs, but nothing helpful there. Also, ChatGPT doesn't have a clue. I can override the validate methods from the image and video fields, but that is a hacky solution, and `required=False` is supposed to work. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How did you submit the data?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike with React. Axios.

Comment: The problem is your payload.You are sending the image with the value of "null" or something that is not an image.Don't send any value if it's empty or handle it in back-end side

Comment: You should include the request body that is causing the issue.  Without that there isn't much help we can give beyond what @tohidsadeghian said.  It is unlikely that optional fields are broken work in a framework as widely used as DRF.